# Loading remote images

Tags: pantheon-mail

I'm currently experiencing an issue with my mail client where I am unable to download images from my inbox. I suspect this could be due to some incorrect settings or permissions. Does anyone have experience with configuring permissions or troubleshooting similar issues who could provide some guidance?

Distributor ID: Elementary
Description:    elementary OS 7.1 Horus
Release:    7.1
Codename:   horus